# react-router-dom v6 renders a Route when it is supposed to not render it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to render private routes for logged in users. For some reason react-router-dom (v6) renders private routes even if **PrivateRoute** returns **null**. Also, I couldn't see any console.logs from inside PrivateRoute. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It renders Dashboard when you go to *localhost/dashboard* and Settings when you go to *localhost/settings*, even though both components are passed to PrivateRoute, which returns null.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,  document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {Pricing} from './components/Pricing';
import {Dashboard} from './components/Dashboard';
import {Settings} from './components/Settings';
import {Login} from './components/Login';
import {Header} from './components/Header';
import {PrivateRoute} from './components/PrivateRoute';

const App = () => {
  

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/pricing' element={<Pricing />} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({path, element}) => {
    console.log('PrivateRoute');    **// couldn't see this in the console**

    return null;
};
```

Comment: PrivateRoute is your own component? It's always going to render, isn't it?

Comment: @Steve it renders Dashboard and Settings components that are passed to PrivateRoute, when you go to localhost/dashboard and localhost/settings. I should clarify the question.

Comment: This does indeed seem like odd behavior as compared to v5. I noticed even using a `div` still allowed the `Dashboard` component/element to be rendered. It's not clear what purpose a `Route` component serves now (*without digging in the source*). I then looked for an updated auth example and found this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx) example. Looks like custom route components are out in favor of a wrapper component and custom hooks to handle the bouncing.

Comment: @Drew Reese - it looks like any element that has "path" and "element" props will act as Route... Indeed, what is the purpose of Route?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, according to the documentation, the new way to do this looks like this:

```
<Route
    path="/protected"
    element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <ProtectedPage />
        </RequireAuth>
    }
/>
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth

Full code exemple:
https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx